# how - 5%3 is equal to - 2?

Tags: c, printf, modular-arithmetic

I'm learning C basics right now. I have a question which is confusing me little bit. 
My question is how the below program's output is - 2 ?

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
   {
    printf("%d", -5%3);
    return 0 ;
   }
```

Comment: That's not programing, it's maths...

Comment: Depending on which `C` standard you are compiling your program with using the `%` or `\` with negative numbers gives you different results. In The `C89` standard it is stated that if either operand should be negative the result of a division or modulo can be rounded up or down. So `-5 \ 3` could either be `-1` or `-2`. For the case of `%` if any of the two numbers `x` and `y` is negative the sign of `x % y` is implementation dependent in `C89`. In `C99` the result of a division is truncated towards zero. That means `-5 \ 3` is `-1` and `-5 % 3` is `-2`.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator is gives you the remainder left after of integer division.
Then `-5/3 = -1` with `-2` as remainder of division as 3*(-1)=-3 and -5-(-3)=-5+3=-2.

Comment: @cybersoft Sorry. I edited.